# Sharepoint 2010 and DispForm.aspx and adding custom

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I am looking to add either a button to the ribbon or adding a form action button control to a list item display form.

I would like to user to have the ability to email the detail of the list item currently being view.

So far....

I created a new DispForm.aspx ...and then added the form action button control. I set the action to a custom action....then SP2010 created a new Site workflow.

I can edit this workflow..but I do not get fields for the "Current Item". I think this has something to do with the fact that its a site workflow and not a list workflow.

I also tried to edit the code in the DispForm.aspx to change the GUID of the workflow in an attempt to start a list workflow with the button.

help?

Answer (score 0):

What I did to get this setup is first create a list workflow.

All work below is done in SharePoint Designer.  And I did not edit any pages just created a custom action that showed up in the ribbon.

You can do this by selecting list and libraries from navigation then selecting the list you want to add the workflow to.  Once you select that there should be a "block" for workflows just click add a new workflow.  With that you can design your workflow and you will have access to current item.

Once you are done with the workflow find the Custom Actions block on the List page (It is below the workflows block for me).  Click some where in the block and on the top ribbon you should see Custom Action.  When you open up that menu it gives you the option to select the type of action (Ribbon, DetailView, ...).  Now just link it to your workflow you just created. (You may have to refresh the list to get the workflow to show up.  If it still doesn't show up make sure you published it).